# Add items to user's cart in Craft Commerce 2

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2

I'm trying to add items to user's cart from a plugin but I'm stuck on getting cart of a user other then current user.

I have the code for adding items to cart, it's something I used on current user. But I don't know how to get the cart for any user.

```
<?php
$cart = iHaveNoIdeaHowToGetUsersCart($user->id); // <---
// I used this for current user:
// $cart = craft\commerce\Plugin::getInstance()->getCarts()->getCart();
if ($cart->id == null) {
    // Create cart if it does not exist
    Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($cart);
}

$purchasableId = Craft::$app->getGlobals()->getSetByHandle('booking')->breakProduct->one()->id;
$options = [
    'amount' => (float)$something,
    'description' => 'Something'
];
$newLineItem = Plugin::getInstance()->getLineItems()->createLineItem($cart->id, $purchasableId, $options, 1);
$cart->setLineItems([$newLineItem]);
Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($cart);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Commerce, a User (or guest with an email address for that matter) can have multiple carts (or unfinished orders).

So we need to get the most recently *active* one. Something like this should work:

```
$query = Order::find();
$query->id($whateverId); // you could also use $query->email 
$query->isCompleted(false);
$query->orderBy('dateCreated DESC');
$cart =  $query->one();

... // rest of your code
```